# Hacer buen uso de media query con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaqueries

```js
$('body').css('background','darkblue');
var desktop = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)');
function cambiarColor(){
if(desktop.matches){
$('body').css('background','darkorange');   
} 
 }

cambiarColor(desktop);
desktop.addListener(cambiarColor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hola a todos, estaba practicando con media querys desde javascript, y veo que no es tan 'fácil' como usar media query desde css, tengo ese script básico, que cambia de color de fondo a naranja cuando la pantalla tiene un ancho de 1024, y cuando es mayor a 1024 es azul, pero aqui hay un pequeño problema, que solo funciona recargando la página. Para resolver esto basta con agregar un else despues del if y especificar un color de fondo azul pero ya lo estoy especificando cuando se carga el documento, entonces ¿Existe una  mejor manera de usar media query desde javascript?, es decir, que se comporte tal y cual a una media query, como ya saben si especificas en una hoja de estilo: `body{ background-color: darkblue; }` y luego agregas una media query: `@media (max-width: 1024px) { body{ background-color: darkorange; } }` , se aplican los estilos dados a las medidas de pantalla especificadas, siempre que la pantalla sea igual o menor a 1024px, se va aplicar un color oscuro naranja, y ya saben lo que pasa cuando es mayor. Asi que, ¿Existe una  mejor manera de usar media query desde javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre es como en css agregar los dos media querys:

```
$('body').css('background','darkblue');
window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)').addEventListener("change",(e) => { if (e.matches) { $('body').css('background','darkorange'); } });
window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1025px)').addEventListener("change",(e) => { if (e.matches) { $('body').css('background','darkblue'); } });
```

**Nota**: el método addListener se encuentra en deshuso.

Se asigna el color al inicio ya que el evento change se ejecuta es cuando cambia el valor, al cargar la página no hay un cambio entonces queda sin asignarse el css.

Comment: recién veo tu respuesta, gracias por responder ! tambien lo pude conseguir con el siguiente codigo const desktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1025px)');
function desktop_responsive(){
 if(desktop.matches){
 $('body').css('background','darkblue'); 
 }
} 

desktop_responsive(desktop);
desktop.addListener(desktop_responsive);

 const tablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)');
function tablet_responsive(){
    if (tablet.matches){
       $('body').css('background','darkorange');
 }
}

tablet_responsive(tablet);
tablet.addListener(tablet_responsive);